# Java threads - wait for condition and condition change

Tags: java, multithreading

I need to implement a test that uses threads in Java that waits for a condition, then does something to make the condition be false and during that check the condition is false. The exact scenario is below. I am new to threads in general, and threads in Java in particular (never used threads in any coding language). The scenario is like this:

1. wait for a file in linux to have the value 1 (using cat on the file)
2. once the value 1 is found, run ping on the linux machine, during the ping I need to verify the value in the same file is 0 during the entire ping session
3. after ping ends I need to verify the value in the file is 1 again

Could you direct me to a simple example on how to do this in Java using threads?

Thanks..

Comment: Looks like producer - consumer problem. Check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem

Answer (score 0):

The general approach is to start a thread and use some synchronisation mechanizm to identify when your thread compleate the job.
One of the methods can be using of ExecutorService and awaitTermination, second approach may be using of CountDownLatch:

```
CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(2);
Thread myThead1 = new MyThread(latch);
Thread myThead2 = new MyThread(latch);
myThread1.start();
myThread2.start();

// This will block execution until myThead1 and myThead2 will call countDown:
latch.await();
```

The thread implementation should call countDown method after job is complited:

```
public class MyThread extends Thread {

    private final CountDownLatch latch;

    public MyThread(CountDownLatch latch) {
        this.latch = latch;
    }

    public void run() {
        // do your job here
        latch.countDown();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I'm not sure how to use this approach for my test. I thought maybe I need one thread to run that keeps checking the file, when the value is 1 then it needs to tell the main program to start the ping and then the thread should wait for 0 value, and then when ping ends the thread again needs to wait for 1, but I'm not sure if this is good and if so how to implement it

Answer (score 0):

Please check java-doc for `java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition`. There is a good example that you can use as a base for your code.